# Is it possible to make a div position relative to a non parent div or is there a better way?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a FAQ page for a rustic home furnishings company. The questions are buttons that, when clicked, expand to show the answer. As of right now, I either have to put the footer way down so it never overlaps which looks awful, or let it overlap, which also looks awful.

The problem is, the buttons (and text they reveal) need to be centered in a secondary background, but the footer needs to span 100% width of the page. If I make the footer a child of the questions div `width=100%` makes it only span the questions div.

I want the footer to move down as the questions' answers are expanded, so I need the footer's vertical position to be relative to the questions div.

```
<div id="questions" class="auto-style22" style="position: absolute; width: 591px; height: 466px; z-index: 8; left: 395px; top: 323px">
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleMe(a){
 //Collapse all answers
   var elements=document.getElementsByClassName("button");
   for (var i=0;i<elements.length;i+=1){
    elements[i].style.display = 'none';
   }
 //Toggle a particular answer
 var e=document.getElementById(a);
 if(!e) return true;
 if(e.style.display=="none"){
  e.style.display="block"
 }
 else{
  e.style.display="none"
 }
 return true;   
}</script>

<input type="button"  onclick="return toggleMe('para1');" value="What is Buffalo Ranch?" class="buttonClass"><br>
<div class="button" id="para1" style="display:none" >

    <br>Buffalo Ranch Rustic Home Furnishings is a locally owned and operated retail store featuring a unique collection of ranch and lodge décor, western art, fine antiques, and collectibles. We have a variety of taxidermy mounts, hair on hide leather furniture and other leather goods (bags, wallets, coasters, etc). We also carry beautiful western inspired jewelry, bedding and gifts. We have everything you need to accessorize yourself and your rustic home, except the fresh country air, that is!
</div>
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="return toggleMe('para2')" value="Where are you located?" class="buttonClass"><br>
<div class="button" id="para2" style="display:none" >
<br>
We are located at 123 Main Street in the quaint and historic little town of Nowhere.
</div>
</div>
div id="footer" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 125px; top: 966px; left: 0px;">
    <img class="footer" height=475 src="Graphics/Blue%20Footer.png" width="100%"></div>
```

Obviously there are a lot more questions but I only included 2 to keep it short.

EDIT: http://postimg.org/image/lvw5edn0r/ There's a screenshot of how I have it now. The footer starts low and is static, but it doesn't look right until a question is opened because there is just a bunch of blank space.

Comment: Seriously I dont understand what you want to do. Can you post some image or refer some website so we can understand your requirement.

Comment: What do you exactly want? Do you want to restrict the question div to overlap to the footer div?

Comment: Make the `#questions` position as `relative` and try, if you could share a screenshot or fiddle it would be great.

Comment: [Screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/lvw5edn0r/) There's a screenshot of the way it is now. The footer just starts way down so it can't overlap it, but that looks bad until a question is opened. 

The problem with setting the position relative and making it a child of the questions div is that the footer needs to span 100% width of the page, not 100% width of the questions div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `#questions` `position` as relative, remove `height` and add `min-height:200px` (or any other value), remove `top` property from `#footer`. Now if you click on any button the footer automatically goes down.

```css
#questions{
 min-height: 200px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#footer{
 background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="questions" class="auto-style22" style="position: relative; width: 591px; z-index: 8;">
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleMe(a){
 //Collapse all answers
   var elements=document.getElementsByClassName("button");
   for (var i=0;i<elements.length;i+=1){
    elements[i].style.display = 'none';
   }
 //Toggle a particular answer
 var e=document.getElementById(a);
 if(!e) return true;
 if(e.style.display=="none"){
  e.style.display="block"
 }
 else{
  e.style.display="none"
 }
 return true;   
}</script>

<input type="button"  onclick="return toggleMe('para1');" value="What is Buffalo Ranch?" class="buttonClass">
<div class="button" id="para1" style="display:none" >

    <br>Buffalo Ranch Rustic Home Furnishings is a locally owned and operated retail store featuring a unique collection of ranch and lodge décor, western art, fine antiques, and collectibles. We have a variety of taxidermy mounts, hair on hide leather furniture and other leather goods (bags, wallets, coasters, etc). We also carry beautiful western inspired jewelry, bedding and gifts. We have everything you need to accessorize yourself and your rustic home, except the fresh country air, that is!
</div>
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="return toggleMe('para2')" value="Where are you located?" class="buttonClass">
<div class="button" id="para2" style="display:none" >
We are located at 123 Main Street in the quaint and historic little town of Nowhere.
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer" style="position: relative; width: 100%; left: 0px;">FOOTER LINKS
   <!-- <img class="footer" height=475 src="Graphics/Blue%20Footer.png" width="100%"> --></div>
```

Comment: Sahil, Thanks for your suggestion. When I run your code snippet the footer does to I not move relative to the questions. I suspect this is because the footer div is not a child of the questions div, but I can't make it a child of the questions div and get it to span 100% width of the page instead of its parent div.

Comment: You check it in snippet now, I have reduced the min-height of #questions so that movement of footer is clearly visible.